# Trace the syscalls from a Docker container

Tags: docker, rust, system-calls

Is there any way to trace the system calls from a container with ptrace?

I want to trace/observe the system calls made by a container from host. I wrote some code in rust like bellow and trace the cmd with the dependency `pete = 0.9.0`, which helps to use ptrace in rust

```
let mut cmd = Command::new("docker");
cmd.args(["exec", "container_id", "./the_program_for_test"]);
```

As the_program_for_test which run in the container, i wrote it with

```
pub fn mkdir_access() {
    let file_path = "src/data/to_create_dir\0";
    ///call the system call mkdir///
    let creat_result = unsafe{syscall2(Sysno::mkdir, file_path.as_ptr() as usize, 0777)};
    match creat_result {
        Ok(n) => println!("success create a directory: {:?}", n),
        Err(e) => println!("create err: {:?}", e),
    }
    ///call the system call rmdir///
    let rmdir = unsafe{syscall1(Sysno::rmdir, file_path.as_ptr() as usize)};
    match rmdir {
        Ok(n) => println!("success delete a directory: {:?}", n),
        Err(e) => println!("remove err: {:?}", e),
    }
}
```

The result shows not only one pid, but none of them are the same as the pid of container's. Otherwise it only shows two println one by one, and there should be a syscall `rmdir` between two of them.

```
...
pid: 7474, syscallno 1."write", regs: 1, 824638660616, 60, 60, 1, 824634425536.
success create a directory: 0
success delete a directory: 0
pid: 7474, syscallno 0."read", regs: 7, 824638660608, 32777, 32777, 1, 824639653120.
...
```

To do this, first i start the container from the terminal, the i run the rust code to execut the program in the container.

I know that use `docker container top id` and `strace` can get the pid of the container and trace it. But can i realize this through a control code in rust with ptrace? or is there any way to locate the running container's pid from the host?

Thanks for the notice

Comment: Worth noting that docker is a client/server architecture. When `docker exec` is running your command, it is actually sending a request to the docker daemon, and that daemon actually runs your command. This means that if you ptrace the `docker exec`, you will not see anything done by the container. If you could work out the PID of the rust process, you could use the attach API of pete to trace the process. That does have a race condition, though - the container may be finished before you start tracing it.

Comment: @NickODell yes, i noticed that problem, so i was so confused whether there are some ways to solve this. Do you know, is there any way to make the program to wait a signal to continue? Maybe i can set a wait point in the program in the container and trigger it by the signal from host?

Comment: One possible way to do that would be for the program to use the kill syscall to send a SIGSTOP signal to itself. That will pause execution. Then, the tracing program attaches ptrace, and sends a SIGCONT signal to resume execution.